# Низкий FPS из-за блокировки Canvas

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

Представленный ниже игровой цикл находится в классе расширяющем Thread и хоть я добавляю отрисовку хоть убираю, fps практически не изменятся. Это говорит о том, что отрисовка много сил у процессора не отнимает. Проблемный кусок в этом цикле вот:

```
 canvas = this.surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
 if (canvas == null) continue;
```

Если убрать этот кусок кода, всё выполняется настолько быстро , что в операции деления для Fps в знаменателе появляется ноль. Т.е. цикл начинает выполняться очень быстро и значит этот указанный выше мною кусок кода проблемный. На эмуляторе я получаю 27 fps при условии, что я вообще ничего не рисую и не считаю. Всё время уходит на блокировку канвы. Почему так много времени, что с этим можно сделать?

```
    while (running) {
        beginTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
        tickCount++;

        canvas = null;
        // пытаемся заблокировать canvas
        // для изменения картинки на поверхности
        try {
            canvas = this.surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
            if (canvas == null)
                continue;

            synchronized (surfaceHolder) {

                //Тут  обновляю координаты и рисую      
            }
        } finally {
            // в случае ошибки, плоскость не перешла в
            //требуемое состояние
            if (canvas != null) {
                surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }
        }

        long x = System.currentTimeMillis() - beginTime;
        long x1 = 1000 / x;
        System.out.println("FPS= " + x1);    
    }
```

Comment: Можно попробовать использовать nanoTime() : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime()

Comment: моя проблема не в делении на  ноль. А в том что блокировка или разблокировака канвы проходят слишком долго.